# Select column header if column contains specific string

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I have a large tab-delimited file in which each column is a patient and each row shows the genotype for a specific position, where missing data is denoted by ./.
I want to extract the column headers of columns that contain missing genotypes at any of the positions.

Example:

```
Variant  P_1  P_2  P_3
var_1    0/0  ./.  1/0
var_2    ./.  ./.  0/0
var_3    1/0  ./.  1/0
```

Expected output

```
P_1
P_2
```

I tried -unsuccessfully:

```
code=$(                
  awk '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++)
        if ($i == "./.") {printf NR==1, sep "\n"}
    }' file
) &&   
awk "{print $code}" file
```

Would be happy for any suggestions!

Answer (score 3):

Save the headers as an array in the first record, then save the column indices for occurrences of `./.` in the following records. Finally, output the header items based on the saved column indices:

```bash
awk '
  NR==1 {split($0,h); next}
  {for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if ($i == "./.") a[i]}
  END {for (i in a) print h[i]}
'
```

```
P_1
P_2
```

Answer (score 1):

Using any awk:

```
$ awk '
    NR == 1 {
        n = split($0,h) - 1
        delete h[1]
        next
    }
    index($0,"./.") {
        for ( i in h ) {
            if ( $i == "./." ) {
                print h[i]
                if ( --n == 1 ) {
                    exit
                }
                delete h[i]
            }
        }
    }
' file
P_2
P_1
```

That's efficient because:

1. `index($0,"./.")` means we only loop on fields in lines that contain at least one `./.` and skip the rest. If almost every line contains a `./`, though, then just remove this call to `index()`.
2. `for (i in h)`, combined with `delete h[i]`, only loops through the
   remaining fields that haven't been found to contain `./.` yet rather
   than looping through all fields, including those previously
   reported, using `for (i=1; i<=NF; i++)`.
3. `if (--n == 0) exit` exits as soon as there are no fields left to test rather than reading the rest of the input.

Answer (score 1):

> Would be happy for any suggestions!

Firstly *transpose* your data then find 1st fields of rows, where there is `./.` anywhere. If you are strictly limited to GNU `AWK` then adapt already existing solution e.g. one presented by [`awk.freeshell.org`](http://awk.freeshell.org/Transpose), if you have choice of tools you might use GNU `datamash` combined with GNU `AWK` following way, let `file.tsv` content be

```
Variant P_1 P_2 P_3
var_1   0/0 ./. 1/0
var_2   ./. ./. 0/0
var_3   1/0 ./. 1/0
```

then

```
datamash transpose < file.tsv | awk 'index($0,"./."){print $1}'
```

gives output

```
P_1
P_2
```

Explanation: [transpose](https://www.gnu.org/software/datamash/manual/html_node/Reverse-and-Transpose.html#Transpose) means move element at (x,y) to (y,x) thus each row becomes column. Then I pipe output to `awk` command where for line which contain `./.` (I use [`index` string function](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html) to avoid need to counterbalance `.` which has special meaning in regular expressions) I `print` its' 1st field value.

*(tested in GNU datamash 1.7 and GNU Awk 5.1.0)*

Answer (score 0):

What I would do:

```
awk '
    NR==1{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) header[i]=$i;next}
    { for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if ($i=="./.") a[header[i]]++ }
    END{for (i in a) print i}
' file
```

```
P_1
P_2
```